# Ruby/Shell: "puts"/"cat"ing an obscure file messes up terminal

Tags: ruby, shell, undefined-behavior

I tried to rewrite some bash commands for Windows in Ruby, and trying to cat some system file totally messes up terminal: It randomly scrolls up (Windows) or down (Linux)

The file in question is this one:

http://danyel.apus.uberspace.de/somefile

and my Ruby program is this:

```
#!/package/host/localhost/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
#cat.rb
File.open(ARGV[-1], "r") do |f|
    puts f.read
    f.close
end
```

If I "cat" the file (via bash), the behaviour turns out to be totally random, too.

Is there a reason why that's the case?

Thanks for help,

Regards,
Danyel.

Comment: No weird scrolling for me (OS X/zsh). Your terminal apparently (mis)interprets some of the characters as escape sequences. Why do you want to print a binary file on the standard output?

Comment: it was just a random file that I fed my application with for testing and I observed this behaviour and was curious about it

Comment: Might be worth to narrow down the characters that are causing the scrolling. (i.e. if you have some time to kill)

Comment: An obscure part is that my C program that "cat"s a file does so as expected and there is no undefined behaviour with it. Only after I switched to ruby this terminal scrolling occurred. My C code: http://pastie.org/7649802

Comment: Your C code open the file in text mode (`"rt"`) whereas your Ruby code uses binary mode (`"r"`).

Comment: Thanks for this small information. If I cat the file using "rt" in Ruby it prints like 1000 lines to my terminal and the scrolling is still messed up

Comment: Have you tried binary mode in your C program?

Answer (score 0):

That file looks like a database... And if you inspect it on console you'll see the hexadecimal literals. You can make it 'readable' like this:

```
puts File.read('path/to/file').unpack('H*')
```